# i cant take my value in asynctask on android

Tags: java, android, string, android-asynctask

```
String[] a = new String[2];
String[] b = new String[2];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    new AsyncTaskClass().execute();
    // in here when i use a it gets me a but i write a = b in method().
}

class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        method();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    }
}

void method() {
    a = b;
}
```

method() is working i put a toast messg in it and i saw the mssg,but it doesnt work(a=b)
by the way a and b is defined.we call that a={"a","b"}; b={"c","d"}; when i use a[0] code gets me "a". why? this is the question

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand your problem.

Comment: Don't write everything in a single sentence, it's hard to understand.

Comment: my eng not perfect this is my best for explain

Comment: you declaring in string array, by your question a[0] - it will return a first value in the array

Answer (score 2):

doInBackground is being executed in background thread, so once you call .execute(), execution will pass your:

```
 //in here when i use a it gets me a but i write  a = b in method().
```

line, and your doInBackground will certainly not yet execute (but it might), you should move all your processing to onPostExecute if it depends on doInBackground  results.